# Transformation of negative ordinate values from a .itiff file

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have multiple iTIFF files which were georeferenced by another person (CRS EPSG 31468, 3 degree GK Zone 4). The problem is that the ordinate (northing) comes with a negative sign while it should be positive. Therefore if I load them into QGIS, the picture appears in the southern hemisphere, while it should be in the northern. Also it is mirrored upside down, which perfectly makes sense due to the negative values.

Is there a possibility of either batch converting these negative values for y into positive ones (sort of a multiplication with -1) or changing the reading behaviour of QGIS that it ignores the (-).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While Tagged Image File Format (TIFF) files are well known, "itiff" are less so. It might help to describe how you obtained them.

Comment: iTIFF is a TIFF file with some undocumented vendor specific features. I guess the format was developed by Bentley for its image server. I would convert all files into standard GeoTIFFs if only possible. https://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/w/microstation__wiki/8866/raster-file-format-handling.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the "itiff" format either but as long as it is a raster, the Raster Calculator (Raster -> Raster Calculator) with the following expression should help you:

```
 if ( "raster_name" < 0, "raster_name" * -1, "raster_name")
```